# Placing files in jre bin through java code

Tags: java

I want to place some files either it could be a jar file or dll's in jre ext folder and bin folder, can i put it in these folders through my java code. or is there a restriction over it of placing the files through writing a code.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You should never need to modify the Java installation directory.

Comment: @Joachim: There are cases where it makes *some* sense (e.g., globally upgrading your JRE to use a later version of a JSR'ed API) but it's pretty horrible for any other reason, and shouldn't be done by a normal application in any case. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/index.html

Comment: @Donal: the **only** cases where this would be appropriate would be in installers. And even then it would be the saner option to provide a private copy of the JDK (modifying the global, public one **will** lead to problems).

Comment: @Joachim bascially i dont want an installer because i am using an applet and applet is using those jar's and dll's because applet will be downloaded on client side which i have to place the dll and jar file in jre/bin and jre/lib/ext to achieve the functionality. but according to you and many of the forums i cannot access the programfiles path in which jre exist.

Comment: You want an **applet** to write to system directories?! That's ill-advised on so many levels that I feel it's important that you explain just why you think this is necessary.

Comment: @Joachim: Adding extra directories to the endorsed path is saner, indeed.

Comment: @Donal...yeah Donal. ok lets suppose i dont want applet to write to system directories then what would be the possible solution to place the jar and dll in jre/bin and jre/lib/ext. "Place it manually"?

Comment: @Java: If I was in your position, I'd be contemplating splitting the app into a server side part that can be configured to have access to everything needed, and a client side part that requires no changes. The other alternative might be Java Web Start, but I don't know too much about that and you'd still be trying to fight your way through several layers of security policies that all say “don't do that”.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple file IO to do that (or e.g. use Apache's commons IO that has a ready made "copy" function)

But the problem is that a user program is usually not allowed to write into the "Program Files" directory.

So you would require administration privileges to run your program, which is not a good idea (unless we are talking about an installation routine)

Comment: ok if i can use by using simple File IO then it means that i need to access the jre bin and ext directory then how would i do that to access the jre directory, or your point is clear that user program is not allowed to place the files in it.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is run with proper privileges, then it can definitely place any files in the `jre/bin` directory.

A couple of points though:

- If you're relying on that file being present in the directory, avoid it.
- jre/ directory will typically be `$JAVA_HOME`

Cheers